# Capybara expect the page to have 2 different contents in the table column

Tags: ruby, capybara

I just need to validate two different items in one column. For example if the column of the table writes Yes and No and I want to confirm if these items that are in the column correspond to yes and no..

This method I validate only one item and if I want to validate two items?.

```
expect(page).to have_css("td:nth-child(5)", exact_text:"YES") #What if I want to validate YES and NO?
```

Comment: you could write a second expectation or spec for NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to check if tr text contain either `YES` or `NO`.

```rb
expect(page).to have_css("td:nth-child(5)", :text => /^(YES|NO)$/) # What if I want to validate YES and NO?
```